# How to access key/value data from form.submit()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a Rails app I'm using jquery to intercept a form submit and perform some functions on the data.

The form response looks something like the following:

```
"object"=>{"parent_id"=>"1", "array_of_strings"=>["string1", "string2", ......]}
```

I need to get the `parent_id`, and then each of the strings from `array_of_strings`

```
$('#myForm').submit ->
  $this = $(this)
  dataArray = $this.serializeArray()

  i = 0
  while i < dataArray.length
    if dataArray[i].name == 'object[parent_id]'
      parent = dataArray[i].value
  i += 1

  i = 0
  while i < dataArray.length
    if dataArray[i].name == 'object[array_of_strings][]'
      string = dataArray[i].value
      //do something with parent and string
  i += 1
```

Is this the best approach? It seems overly comlpex to iterate through the entire form response to access a key/value. My jquery/ javascript knowledge is limited, and I wonder if there is a better way that is more commonly used?

Comment: I believe some information are missing, you want to get the information **where**? Do you need them in Rails controller or you need them in the Javascript code? If you need it **in javascript code**, then you are almost there. From my understanding, you have a JSON which you can convert to in memory data with `JSON.parse(dataArray)`, which you will be able to access as a normal array. Also, you might want to remove `ruby-on-rails` tag if you need it in javascript only, and possibly add javascript tag.

Comment: thanks @Fire-Dragon-DoL, this looks promising. But how do I access only the json string mentioned in the question? `serializeArray` returns form field names, values, etc. If all I want is the submitted from response as above? BTW this entirely client side - I've retagged the question as you suggested

Comment: Once you convert the array with something like `obj = JSON.parse(dataArray)`, you can access it with two javascript notations: `obj.parent_id; obj.array_of_strings` or `obj['parent_id']; obj['array_of_strings']` both are fine except the first won't work if the key contains spaces.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.parse(dataArray))` gives `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o`. How do I get the array in the first place? `$this.serializeArray()` does not provide the array as listed in my questions - I have taken this from the server logs. My question is how do I extract only this information from the data posted by the form.

Comment: OK, it appears that `JSON.stringify` is the function needed. But even then I would need to use `filter` to iterate through the response. I think I will just stick with what I have unless I've overlooked something

Answer (score 0):

You can reference any form field by its `name` or `id` attribute using [jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and modify fields values using jQuery's `val()` function to retrieve or set form field values. I've wrote a complete example that shows how to retrieve and modify form values on form submit and then finally pass them (modified) to server. Of course, it is not the only way you can do it.

```
var form = $("#myForm");
var parentIdField = form.find("[name=parentId]");
var someOtherField = form.find("[name=sameOtherField]");
form.on("submit",modifyFormFieldsAndSubmit);

function modifyFormFields(submitEvent) {
   // retrieve field value
   var parentIdFieldValue = parentIdField.val();
   // modify parentIdFieldValue ... and set it back to field
   parentIdField.val("someNewValue");
   // do the same for other fields you want to modify ...
   // finally submit modified fields values to server
   // note that 'form' reference jQuery extended form and 'form[0]'
   // reference underlying HTML form element
   form[0].submit();       
}
```